# How to call controller function in view in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-touch-2.1

I have one function in controller. It will return a value. I have called that function in view using `renderer:this.getController('test.controller.Barchart').change();` but it is not working. I am getting an error wind has no method `getController()`. Can anybody tell me how to call it correctly?

Comment: YOU_APP_NAME.app.getController('MyController')

Answer (score 6):

Having a view call a controller is considered the essence of evil. The view should never be aware of the controller. I'm a lead on a large project that uses ExtJS and we don't allow anything in our views other than the JSON description of the view. The logic that is looking for a controller should likely be in the controller itself.

Comment: Since I learning/working with ExtJS not that long ago I've a question. How do you handle view listener events without calling controller? Say I have a grid, and I want to execute a controller function on row select event? How do you do that without calling controller from view listener?

Answer (score 5):

please refer below solution!!!

```
var ControllerRef=<applicationreference>.getController(<ControllerfolderPath>.controllerName);
ControllerRef.<ControllerFunction>();
```

Example:

```
var MyApp = Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', { 
               ......
               ......
            });

var ControllerRef  =   MyApp.getController('general.ManagerController');
ControllerRef.MyFunction();
```

Thanks

Comment: whether i need to create instance MyApp in view? am getting MYApp is not defined

Comment: it's not exactly MyApp reference, but reference to View that has this controller set. In my application I call LoginBtn.click of LoginWin with this code: `Ext.ComponentManager.get('LoginWin').getController().onLoginClick();` while MyApp is another window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You can put your controller as a global variable in your app.js like so:

```
Ext.define('MySharedData', {
    my_Controller:Object

});
```

In your controller:

```
MySharedData.my_Controller=this.getController('<ControllerfolderPath>.controllerName');
```

then call the function that you want, from your view:

```
 MySharedData.my_Controller.my_Function();
```